# When a car or a human body gets riddled severely

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Please imagine you in a gunfire a car / someone's body gets riddled with bullets as the linked pictures. As you will notice at first glance, you will see a big difference between the amount of the hit bullets to the target [a car or even a human body.]

Who would a native speaker differentiate these two from one another in English:

[image]

[image]

What I can say here would be something like:

> They've riddled the car.

Or

> The car got riddled.

Which can be used only for the first picture. But what about the second one which has gotten much more riddled?

Comment: You could use _riddled_ for either picture. In fact, I'd be more inclined to use it for the second picture than the first. In my opinion, [the more bullet holes are in the car](http://img1.izismile.com/img/img7/20140729/640/armored_jeep_survives_hundreds_of_bullets_640_01.jpg), the more I think _riddled_ is a good word to use.

Comment: What @J.R. says. It's probable that few people who use the word know this, but the verb *riddle* in this sense is derived from a noun meaning a coarse 'sieve'--so the verb becomes more appropriate as the proportion of holes to solids increases.

Answer (score 1):

For your first picture

> The car has some bullet holes.
>   The car has a dozen bullet holes.

For your second picture

> P1: What does the car look like?
>
> P2: The car is riddled with bullet holes, too many to count.
>         The car is covered with bullet holes, too many to count.
>
> P1: How badly?
>   P2: Like Swiss Cheese.

[image]
<sub>(source: [bgr.com](http://cdn.bgr.com/2015/05/swiss_cheese.jpg?quality=98&strip=all))</sub>